# How to use html2canvas JavaScript with Selenium webdriver in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

With selenium webdriver, I would test [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/build/html2canvas.js) JS script to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it, directly on the browser.
I have a written this C# code to test it, but obj is always null.

*C# Code for reference*

```
        IWebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.monsite.com");

        string scriptJS = File.ReadAllText("html2canvas.js");
        scriptJS += @"
            html2canvas(document.body, {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    return img;
                }
            });";

        IJavaScriptExecutor executorJS = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        var obj = executorJS.ExecuteScript(scriptJS);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two thinks that are wrong:

1. `return img` is value that is retured by `onrendered` function. That means `html2canvas()` call doesn't return image as you expect in your code.
2. `executorJS.ExecuteScript` returns IWebElement, Int64, Boolean, String, List<IWebElement|Int64|Boolean|String> or null. So you can't get this image as return value, see for more details the [doc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor_ExecuteScript.htm).

If you need screenshot of site, you can use use `((ITakesScreenshot) driver).GetScreenshot();` ([doc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_ITakesScreenshot.htm)).

If you need image in this site, you have to implement it into `onrendered` function.

---

**UPDATE (25.10.2013)**

You can call `executorJS.ExecuteAsyncScript`. Last parameter in javascript function call will be callback function injected by webdriver. Async method returns after injected method 
is called, or scriptTimeout is done. For this reason it is a good idea to set timeout to higher value (just to ensure that application is running like expected, later you can put value that is used in productive system).

```
    Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    scriptJS += @"
        var webDriverCallback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];

        html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');;
                webDriverCallback(img);
            }
        });";

    IJavaScriptExecutor executorJS = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    var obj = executorJS.ExecuteAsyncScript(scriptJS);
```

The result is base64 encoded image as String.

Comment: I would test html2canvas because with this script it is possible to  take "screenshots" of parts of webpages (Div, ...). This is not possible with `((ITakesScreenshot) driver).GetScreenshot();`